# Scala : placeholder inside tuple

Tags: scala, tuples

I've played a bit with placeholder and found a strange case :

```
val integers = Seq(1, 2)
val f = (x:Int) => x + 1
integers.map((_, f(_)))
```

which returns

```
Seq[(Int, Int => Int)] = List((1,<function1>), (2,<function1>))
```

I was expecting

```
Seq[(Int, Int)] = List((1, 2), (2, 3))
```

If I make the following changes, everything works as expected :

```
integers.map(i => (i, f(i)))
```

Any idea why the function `f` is not applied during the mapping ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Scala compiler can't read your mind, so the `_` placeholder syntax is only useful in very simple expressions.

In your example:

```
integers.map((_, f(_)))
```

it evaluates the `f(_)` as a standalone sub-expression, so you end up with something equivalent to this:

```
x => (x, y => f(y))
```

Even if the compiler didn't treat `f(_)` as its own sub-expression, the result would not be the same as what you say want:

```
integers.map(i => (i, f(i)))
```

You want both instances of `_` to be treated as the same argument, which is not how `_` works. Each occurrence of `_` in an expression is always treated as a unique argument.

Answer (score 5):

The underscore stands in for the passed argument only once.  So in `integers.map((_, f(_)))` the 1st `_` is a value from `integers` but the 2nd `_` has the stand-alone meaning of "partially applied function".

If your anonymous function takes 2 (or more) arguments then you can use 2 (or more) underscores, but each stands in for its passed argument only once.

Comment: In other words @Francis your program is equivalent to: `val integers = Seq(1, 2);
  val f = (x:Int) => x + 1;
  val g = f(_);
  integers.map((_, g))`